# Перемотка видео не по шкале JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, видео

Здравствуйте. Ребят не могу разобраться. Попытался сделать 360 видео, в котором перемотка вперед и назад осуществляется при помощи mouse drag, реализовал это все дело на mousewhell, но оно все жутко лагат, просто нереальные задержки.

http://webven.ru/portfolio/video/index.html

Возможно кто-то уже делал подобное? Возможно есть плеер, у которого плавная перемотка, которой можно управлять при помощи доп функций. Помогите :(

Comment: Вообще в js есть специальные функции по этому поводу. Если хотите могу кинуть ссылку на список функций

Comment: Или если вы с таким не сталкивались, посмотрите пожалуйста код core.js, в какую сторону мне вообще копать?

Comment: Вы хотите управлять видео с помощью других элементов? В скрипте всё чисто, вроде бы

Comment: Поменяйте видео. У меня хороший интернет, довольно таки, а видео еле грузит. А остальное неплохо работает